# Custom header in TableView

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Is there any way to insert a (more complex) custom header item into a TableView?

Example:

Each header contains a button to the left of the column title to remove the column from the table and another button beneath it to disable/enable editing.

I am using the Model/View architecture (QAbstractTableModel + TableView) from PyQt4 to design a table. I can set the header titles with

```
def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
```

I found that it is possible to add widgets to the cells with

```
tableView.setIndexWidget(index, widget)
```

but as far as I understood this can't be used for the header items. Also I think I need QItemDelegates for this, but I don't understand how they are used.

Update #1:

Example of a custom header

[image]

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to understand you.

Comment: It would also be good to indicate what you have researched and advanced